# Greyhound bus ticket (print at home)

Tags: buses, greyhound

Really silly question but just to make sure: do I just print my Greyhound bus ticket out and I'm all set for my ticket, or do I need to cut it out? I'm only bringing one bag, could I bring that on the bus?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a suitcase, they may ask to check in (which goes in the check in bin in the belly of the bus). If it's a back pack or something similar, you can carry it with you. As far as the ticket goes, you can print it from your home, print it out from a kiosk at the bus stand or use your smartphone to scan the e ticket and avoid any printing altogether.

Comment: You can't print Greyhound "print at home" tickets at station kiosks or counters. If you want to do this you need to select "will call."